# GROUP domain from url in MySql

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

I have a large database that contains many urls, there are many domains repeating and i;m trying to get only the domain.
eg:

```
http://example.com/someurl.html
http://example.com/someurl_on_the_same_domain.html
http://example.net/myurl.php
http://example.org/anotherurl.php
```

and i want to get only domains, eg:

```
http://example.com
http://example.net
http://example.org
```

My query is:

> SELECT `id`, `site` FROM `table` GROUP
>   BY `site` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 50

I need to use regex i think but i'm not mysql guru.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(site, 1 , LOCATE('/', site, 8)-1)
        as OnlyDomain
    FROM table
    GROUP BY OnlyDomain
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

**[EDIT] :** After OP request, here's the updated answer that will show correct results even if domain names does not have trailing slashes:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(site, 1 , IF(LOCATE('/', site, 8), LOCATE('/', site, 8)-1, LENGTH(site)))
        as OnlyDomain
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY OnlyDomain
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: thx, it seems to be working but when a url only contains domain name (http://google.com and not http://google.com/url.html) it doesn't pulling it

Comment: The edited code works a treat, still reasonably fast as well and saves storing the value separately.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS nCount,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(site,'http://',''),'https://',''),'www.',''),'/',1) AS sDomain 
FROM tbl_table
GROUP BY sDomain 
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Addon after JQman sollution with also the www. replaced and the group by + count

Answer (score 1):

You can use string replacement. Assuming that the "site" column contains the url:

```
select id, 
substr(site,1,locate('/', site ,locate('//',site)+2)-1)
from table 
group by site
order by id
desc limit 50;
```

Be careful to make sure that multiple slashes are encoded, eg:

```
http://example.com/somethingelse/someurl.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(site,'http://',''),'https://',''),'/',1) as domain 
       FROM table
       GROUP BY domain 
       ORDER BY id DESC 
       LIMIT 50
```

That was working for me, if anybody needs it.

Comment: THis one actually works best. I found it here too: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?698370-GROUP-domain-from-url-in-MySql

Answer (score 0):

You can select the domains with:

```
select left(site,6+locate('/',substring(site,8)))
```

Comment: If you need it to work on 'example.com', you should put an example like that in the question.  Looks like you've already solved the problem though.